# assert_not in ch6 rails tutorial - modeling users (conceptual)

Tags: railstutorial.org

Trying to translate this into literal english. The test "name should be present" is saying: an instance of user.name equals an empty string. Then assert that it's not a valid instance of user.name, but since I have not required validation on presence of name YET in my users model, the test goes red? Can someone confirm I have my head on straight? What's a good way to think about assert_not in general? Could someone change it to assert and somehow make it false? Thanks!

```
require 'test_helper'

class UserTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase

  def setup
    @user = User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com")
  end

  test "should be valid" do
    assert @user.valid?
  end

  test "name should be present" do
    @user.name = "     "
    assert_not @user.valid?
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct.

You also could write this test in english as:
Take a user, and assign the name of that user as a bunch of whitespace. I assert that that user should not be valid.

Now, because you've written the test before the code it tests (TDD), your test will fail (which is A-OK). Once you put in your user validation, the user will come back as invalid, and your test will pass.

If you don't love the syntax quoted in your question, you can phrase your test in a different way, e.g.:

```
test "name should be present" do
  @user.name = "     "
  @user.should_not be_valid
end
```